# Can't compare integers with datetime.now()

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, boolean

I'm trying to make boolean and time based program. I tried to make this:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if int(00) and int(00) <= now.time and now.minute <= int(11) and int(59):
print ('morning')
elif int(12) and int(00) <= now.time and now.minute <= int(15) and int(59):
print ('afternoon')
elif int(16) and int(00) <= now.time and now.minute <= int(18) and int(59):
print ('evening')
elif int(19) and int(00) <= now.time and now.minute <= int(23) and int(59):
print ('good night')
```

but it always said

`TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'`

Anyone can help me?

Comment: The error is because you cannot compare `int` and `now.time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it I think ;)

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

if now.hour < 12:
    print ('morning')
elif now.hour < 16:
    print ('afternoon')
elif now.hour < 19:
    print ('evening')
else:
    print ('good night')
```

Answer (score 0):

use `now.hour` instead of `now.time`.
`now.time()` can give `time` object, not `hour`.

And also seems invalid conditions for `if` statement. The expectation maybe

```
if int(00) <= now.hour and now.minute <= int(11) and now.seconds <= int(59): 
   print ('morning')
```

Comment: Changed it, but still does not show up print message

Comment: @Redsec seems some invalid statements in `if`.

Answer (score 0):

in python you can use `x <= y <= z <= w` syntax on if statements:

```
1 <= 2 <= 3 < 4  # evaluates to True
```

only check the hour, also simplified the `if` statements

```
from datetime import datetime


def greeting(now=None):
    now = now or datetime.now()
    if 0 <= now.hour < 12:
        return 'morning'
    if 12 <= now.hour < 16:
        return 'afternoon'
    if 16 <= now.hour < 19:
        return 'evening'
    if 19 <= now.hour:
        return 'night'

print(greeting())  # 18:48:00 evening
print(greeting(datetime(2017, 8, 26, 22, 0, 0)))  # 22:00:00 night
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted:

```
import datetime

# Define hours that different times of day start
start_of_afternoon = 12
start_of_evening   = 16
start_of_night     = 19

# Get current time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

if now.hour < start_of_afternoon: # before 12pm
    print ('morning')
elif start_of_afternoon <= now.hour and now.hour < start_of_evening: # after 12pm and before 4pm
    print ('afternoon')
elif start_of_evening <= now.hour and now.hour < start_of_night: # after 4pm and before 7pm
    print ('evening')
elif start_of_night <= now.hour: # after 7pm
    print ('good night')
```